Add validation to date TextFormField
I faced with the problem of validating text fields.
Here you need to enter the date in the format dd.mm.yyyy. I also use flutter_multi_formatter package for this form.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_multi_formatter/formatters/masked_input_formatter.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: StartPage());
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 300, horizontal: 50),
        child: TextFormField(
          onChanged: (val) {},
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
          inputFormatters: [MaskedInputFormatter('##.##.####')],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

For example, user will start entering an incorrect date format: 32.13.2009. And I want the text with the error notification to appear below this form. Is it possible to add validation for this form if an incorrect date is entered? Maybe it's good to parse the entered text and use conditions to compare numbers. I will be glad any help.

The DateTime.parse already does the date validation. So you can convert the date to string with the original format and then compare if its matching the input.
Ravindra S. Patil ideia to use extension is great, so I only change the validation:
extension DateValidator on String {
  bool isValidDate() {
    final dateArray = this.split(".");

    final day = dateArray[0];
    final month = dateArray[1];
    final year = dateArray[2];

    final date = DateTime.parse('$year$month$day');

    final originalFormatString = toOriginalFormatString(date);
    return this == originalFormatString;
  }

  String toOriginalFormatString(DateTime dateTime) {
    final day = dateTime.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final month = dateTime.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final year = dateTime.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0');

    return "$day.$month.$year";
  }
}

Example of use:
void main() {
  print("37.15.2009".isValidDate()); // false
  print("37.12.2009".isValidDate()); // false
  print("31.15.2009".isValidDate()); // false
  print("30.11.2009".isValidDate()); // true
  print("25.12.2009".isValidDate()); // true
}

On the Widget:
TextFormField(
  onChanged: (val) {},
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
  ),
  inputFormatters: [MaskedInputFormatter('##.##.####')],
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter a date';
    } else if (!value.isValidDate()) {
      return 'Invalid date';
    }

    return null;
  },
),


Try below code I have try using extension:
Extension:
extension DateValidator on String {
  bool isValidDate() {
    final regExp = RegExp(r'^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$');
    if (!regExp.hasMatch(this)) {
      return false;
    }

    final parts = this.split('.');
    final day = int.tryParse(parts[0]);
    final month = int.tryParse(parts[1]);
    final year = int.tryParse(parts[2]);

    if (day == null || month == null || year == null) {
      return false;
    }
    // for day validation
    if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
      return false;
    }
    // for month validation
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
      return false;
    }
    // for year validation 
    // for below you can choose maximum year on your need instead of DateTime.now().year
    if (year < 1900 || year > DateTime.now().year) {
      return false;
    }
    // for feb month validation
    final date = DateTime(year, month, day);
    if (date.day != day || date.month != month || date.year != year) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}

UI:
 TextFormField(
        onChanged: (val) {},
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter a date';
          } else if (!value.isValidDate()) {
            return 'Invalid date';
          }

          return null;
        },
      ),


I suggest you look at Flutter Form Validation doc provided by flutter itself.
Example:
TextFormField(
            // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),


Thanks for the link. It remains to come up with a condition for validating the date. I'll try.
